# IBM UbanCode Deploy - Access property from nested generic processes

Tags: devops, urbancode, ucd

I have an component process that calls a generic process (called Deploy_zOS, inside that generic process there are another 20 generic processes (each with a unique name). I want to get an output property from one of the steps but can't seemt o get the syntax correct. Can anyone help?

Thanks!